# MDX to SSAS calculation

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have written a MDX query which works fine in SQL Server Management Studio.  My query is as follows:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Item Count] 
ON 0 
FROM [Inventory]
where [DateDiscontinued].[Date].[Discontinued Cal Year].&[0].&[0]
```

This query gives me all the items which are Discontinues.Now the problem is that when I copy paste the query in BIDS(SSAS Cube Calculation) as a calculated Member I get an error. It says it can't read the select statement. Do I need to write different MDX to support SSAS Calculated member or different function which supports SSAS Calculated Memeber?

Comment: can you post the create calculated member statement?

Comment: I am just copying the above query into the Calculations in BIDS. But the Select Statement is giving an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [create member right syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144787.aspx) is:

```
CREATE [ SESSION ] [HIDDDEN] [ CALCULATED ] MEMBER CURRENTCUBE | Cube_Name.Member_Name 
   AS MDX_Expression
      [,Property_Name = Property_Value, ...n]
......[,SCOPE_ISOLATION = CUBE]
```

Then ,your create member should be like:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Measures.MyMeasure AS
([Measures].[Item Count] , 
 [DateDiscontinued].[Date].[Discontinued Cal Year].&[0].&[0])
```